# Reason behind my potentiometer getting short circuited or blasted

Tags: potentiometer, short-circuit

I was implementing a small circuit in which I used a potentiometer across the Live and neutral and after a few seconds while I was trying to operate the knob the potentiometer blasted or short-circuit. What could be the possible reason for this as there was no load connected to the device and I know potentiometer are used for small application but as long as no load is connected there should be minimum current flowing through the circuit

My connection were as follows:

```
Potentiometer                      Power-Supply 
Pin 1                                Live
Pin 3                                Neutral
```

Pin 2 is been treated as an output pin.

The schematic is as follows
[image]

No connections were made to the PCB.

Comment: What’s the voltage rating on the potentiometer? Dito for resistance and power.

Comment: What is Dito?
How to know the voltage rating of the potentiometer can you please guide me for the same because I don't know

Comment: Don't do that.  Many potentiometers aren't made for line voltage.  Besides not being rated for line voltage, they may be constructed in such a way that line voltage is on the shaft - or can get to the shaft if it fails some way.  Make sure to use a part rated for the voltage and insulate it so that the user cannot touch any metal parts.

Comment: If you don't know which potentiometer it is and what are its ratings, why did you connect it to mains then? If you don't know what you connected to mains, how can we know why it blew up? You should only connect something to mains when you know what you are doing and can do it safely.

Comment: You check the datasheet. Also, it goes without saying that you should not connect anything to mains if you have any doubt on its ratings. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dito

Comment: I just calculated everything and the rated voltage is 100V and it is 230V AC here. Thank you for your help I know the reason why it blew off now.
Justme and @winny, I will keep your advice in mind from now. Thank you for the help

Comment: @MaazSk Dito is a typo of "ditto" meaning "the same thing". i.e. What's the voltage rating on the potentiometer? What's the power rating on the potentiometer? What's the resistance of the potentiometer?

Comment: Did you calculate the voltage rating from the resistance and power rating? If yes, please be aware that unless stated in the datasheet that that’s how it’s rated, the voltage rating could be even lower than that. Also, if it’s not rated for AC, you need to multiply it with 0.707 to not over stress it with the peak of the AC cycle.

Comment: @winny I calculated on my own as I was unable to find the datasheet of the potentiometer as it was purchased from a local store and they don't have the datasheet or other details. Still I am searching the datasheet of the potentiometer. I will update soon and still there are some questions which needs to be clear I will update them soon. Thank you!

Comment: EE top tip: No datasheet - no sale!